# Where to put helper functions in class based react component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that contains an object where I need to check for duplicate values.

To do that I would like to create a helper function. I just don't know if I should make it a method within the class or a function outside the class scope? What makes the most sense to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd put it in its own file and import it into the consuming component.  From your description it seems like a generic use case that has a good chance of being reused.

Comment: That actually didn't cross my mind. I think I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Sounds good :) Please let me know if you have any issues and please mark the answer as correct if it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the function you are creating is quite generic at least in what comes to your app. Code is quite easy to refactor these days, so I think the actual location is not that important in the beginning. But still, I would prefer to do this kind of code at least to a separate function in some util file instead of the react class file itself. That will make it easier to make unit tests for the code.